Need to replace gas water heater. Questions about my setup
I need to replace an AO Smith Proline (GCR-40 400) natural gas water heater that was manufactured in 2017. It started leaking from the bottom recently. I'm looking at a newer AO Smith ProLine 40 gal (Tall 40 MBH Low NOx Atmospheric Vent Natural Gas Water Heater Part #AGCR4000L010000N). Pictures below.
About the existing setup:

The Temperature and Pressure valve appears to be on top. There is a pipe connected to this valve and routes inside a wall. I don't know where this pipe leads to.

It doesn't have an expansion tank on the cold water line. Many recommend that an expansion tank should be added in a closed loop system.


Questions about the existing setup:

The new model has the T&P valve on the side. Can I cut the PVC pipe currently connected to the old unit and use elbow connectors to extend the pipe to the new T&P valve?

Where does the pipe that is connected to the T&P valve go to? The other side of the wall is the kitchen, on the immediate side of the gas oven and refrigerator.

Is a 2.1 gallon expansion tank sufficient for a 40 gallon water heater?

I read in an AO Smith manual that expansion tank should be pressurized to match the water pressure using a hand pump. Is there a special hand pump for this? Or can I use a regular bike pump?


From what I see in my setup compared to what I have read so far, it appears to be a doable process for DIYers with many instructions available.
Are there other things I need to consider with the replacement?
Thank you!
Pictures of the setup:





In many places you are NOT allowed to DIY gas without training/certification of some type.

Please see [ask], then revise your post to just ask one question, reflected clearly in the title.

You do not have Temperature and Pressure valve. It is a OVER-pressure safety valve, it is there to release the overpressure when it happens. The pipe from it usually goes outside the home again for safety reason (hot water or even steam.
The location of the pressure vale can be on to or on the side close to the top.
If it is leaking at the bottom, first double check if the water is coming from one of the top connections. If not then you have dead boiler (needs replacement)
1  The new model has the T&P valve on the side. Can I cut the PVC pipe currently connected to the old unit and use elbow connectors to extend the pipe to the new T&P valve? -YES
2  Where does the pipe that is connected to the T&P valve go to? The other side of the wall is the kitchen, on the immediate side of the gas oven and refrigerator - It goes to the outside (sticks out of the outside wall You can find it with two people, where one looks for a 1/2 inch PVC pipe, and the other lifts the handle on the over pressure valve to initiate water flow.
Gas heaters are not recommended DIY, get a professional

Thanks for the information! I do see a pipe sticking outside of one of the side walls. I'll double check if that is really it. I'll call a plumber and get this checked out then. It does look like the leak is only coming from the bottom.

You should've flagged this question. It's in clear violation of site policy. See the [help] for a refresher.

Looks like your plastic pipe is C-PVC, not ordinary PVC. Some info on that from the web:
(My understanding is that CPVC use is now deprecated in favor of copper or PEX due to potential failure issues over the long term)
Chlorinated polyvinyl chloride (CPVC) and polyvinyl chloride (PVC) are both thermoplastics used for piping and fittings, but they have several differences
Temperature resistance
CPVC can withstand higher temperatures than PVC, with a maximum service temperature of 200°F compared to PVC's 140°F.
Pressure resistance
CPVC is more pressure resistant than PVC.
Flexibility
CPVC is more flexible than PVC and requires support every three feet to stay in place.
Chemical makeup
CPVC has a different chemical makeup than PVC, so they require different primers and solvents. PVC glue is not strong enough to adhere to CPVC.
Color
CTS CPVC is often a light yellowish color, while schedule 80 CPVC (NPS) is a light gray color. PVC pipe and fittings are usually white or dark gray.
